# Solving a quadratic fractional programming problem

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-forms

I need to solving following quadratic fractional programming problem:
\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix}
\min_w \frac{w^\top Q w}{w^\top (r r^\top) w} \\
\text{s.t.}\quad w\geq 0 \\
\sum w =1
\end{matrix}
\end{equation}
where $w\in\Re^{n,1}$, $Q$ is a given positive definite matrix and $r\in\Re^{n,1}$ is a given vector.

This is my first time solving this kind of problems, do I have do some change of variables first? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_programming), i.e.
\begin{equation}
t=\frac{1}{r^\top w}, \qquad y=tw
\end{equation}
then the original problem becomes
\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix}
\min_y y^\top Q y \\
\text{s.t.}\quad y\geq 0 \\
\sum y = t\\
r^\top y =1
\end{matrix}
\end{equation}

which solver could I use?

Many thanks

Comment: KKT might be useable here

Comment: Do you think the “change of variable” process is correct and necessary?

Comment: The process looks correct and the second problem for me looks easier to solve